# mysql - call to insert into another table on every value of select

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-migration

I'm currently migrating data from our old database schema into a new one.

I have a table called `Product` on my old database, on my new database schema I still have a `Product` table and a new column for `b_id`, and another table `B`.

During migration, I will need to insert an entry to table `B` for every product that I have in my table and update the `Product` table to set the `b_id` for the newly created entry on b for this product. How can I accomplish this?

To transfer the data for the product table, I have:

```
INSERT INTO newSchema.Product
SELECT id, prodName 
FROM oldSchema.Product
```

I'm thinking of looping into the `oldSchema.Product` and for every product, have a call to `INSERT INTO B` and `UPDATE TABLE Product`, but no idea how to put this into code.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have to give us more to go on than this

Answer (score 0):

The same goes for B table...

```
INSERT INTO newschema.B (product_id)
SELECT      id
FROM        oldschema.product
```

**Edited**:

```
CREATE TABLE newschema.b (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         product_id INT,
         PRIMARY KEY (id)
         );

CREATE TABLE newschema.product (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
         b_id INT,
         PRIMARY KEY (id),
         FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b(id)
         );

INSERT INTO newschema.b (product_id)
SELECT      product_id
FROM        oldschema.product ;

INSERT INTO newschema.product (id, name, b_id)
SELECT      OP.id,
            OP.name,
            NB.id
FROM        oldschema.product AS OP,
            newschema.b AS NB
WHERE       NB.product_id = OP.id ;
```

Comment: I don't think I get you but try this and tell me (Notice: I didn't test it)